# Order accept/cancelled and print recipt via GPRS printer from magento2 store?

Tags: magento2, order-status, print

I want a mechanism in which when customer order on my website, shopkeeper at shop gets order request on his GPRS machine, shopkeeper can accept or canceled request from GPRS machine and it will update order status on my web-store as well as when shopkeeper gets order request GPRS machine prints receipt of order for packaging.

I purchase this E_POS GPRS machine for this job (http://www.kmychina.com.cn/en/product/detail.asp?id=940)

as this product owner uploaded video on YouTube how it works its exactly same what I wants to do  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5dPZ2kfacU)

company provides me some necessary documentation about how do I connect to my mailing server , but I'm getting confuse how it connects to my store and change order statuses ? I also contacted them but they ain't replying yet ,that's why I'm asking here for little help .

> Do I need any kind of API for connection this machine to my store for
>   changing order statuses and printing order receipts? along with some CRON job code for checking upcoming orders list ? I need help in code  Please
>   elaborate :)